# this.Invoke throws cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I don't know how to explain that, so here is my code:

```
this.Invoke(listBox1.Items.Add, new Object[] { e.Data.ToString() });
```

But, everything would be ok, if I wouldn't have any errors, but sadly I have 2 errors:

Error   1

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' has some invalid arguments

Error   2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'

What should I do to overcome these exceptions?

Comment: you should have a separate method for your invoke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Invoke` requires you to use a *delegate* as first parameter. `ListBox.Items.Add` is a *method*, not a delegate.

You can, however, use this:

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data.ToString());
});
```

Comment: There's actually no need for the anonymous method here (not that adding it breaks anything either); simply a need to cast to the appropriate delegate.

Answer (score 5):

Set a delegate to work with.

```
Invoke(new Action(() => 
{ 
  // Do it 
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

You batter check if te control needs invoke, if so invoke it:

```
if(listBox1.InvokeRequired)
     listBox1.Invoke((Action)(()=> listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data.ToString())); //if e.Data is the object to add it to listBox!
```

Comment: Presumably he already knows he needs to invoke, and has no need to check programmatically.  This also won't resolve his compile time errors at all.